# If a checkbox isn't checked, do something

Tags: jquery

Having some trouble figuring this one out. If both the checkbox in the second and third `td` is unchecked, then disable the one in the fourth.

```
$('#allergies tbody tr').each(function () {
  if ($('td:eq(1) input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)', $(this)).length > 0 
      && $('td:eq(2) input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)', $(this)).length > 0) {
      $("td:eq(3) input", $(this)).attr('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I was retarded and put false for disabled instead of true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#allergies tbody tr').each(function () {
  if ($('td:eq(1) input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length > 0 
      && $('td:eq(2) input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length > 0) {
      $("td:eq(3) input").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

to the specific ones in the tr use

```
$('#allergies tbody tr').each(function () {
  if ($('td:eq(1) input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)', $(this)).length > 0 
      && $('td:eq(2) input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)', $(this)).length > 0) {
      $("td:eq(3) input", $(this)).prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You logic was right but less readable..
Separate them into smaller chunks

```
$('#allergies tbody tr').each(function () {
    var $this  = $(this);
    var chk1 = $this.find('td:eq(1) input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked');
    var chk2 = $this.find('td:eq(2) input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked');

    // If both are false then disable else 
    // enable them
    if(chk1 === false && chk2 === false){
       $this.find('td:eq(3) input').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else{
       $this.find('td:eq(3) input').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```